# Do ammo capacity bonuses stack?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm playing a soldier and I've got both Incendiary Ammo and Disruptor Ammo at level 4. I see that at level 5 for each, there's an option for +30% ammo.

[image]

I'm trying to plan out my build but don't currently have the skill points to test this out for myself.

- Is this a passive ammo capacity bonus that is in effect even if I'm not using that particular ammo power?
- If so, will the ammo capacity bonus from different ammo (such as Incendiary and Disruptor) powers stack, such that I'd have +60% capacity?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tested this using a **Vanguard** with access to both *Cryo Ammo* and *Incendiary Ammo* at the Shooting Range on the Citadel, with an M-3 Predator with a base ammo capacity of 105 (90 + 15 in Clip).

After learning the Rank 5 *Incendiary Ammo* upgrade for increased capacity, my max ammunition remained the same *until I activated Incendiary Ammo*. After activating the power, the clip size remained at 15, but my reserve capacity jumped from 90 to 116, for a total of 131 rounds.

I then learned the upgrade for *Cryo Ammo*. When activated, the reserve ammunition jumped to 116 again, clip size remained unaffected.

## No, they do not stack, and Yes, they only work when the Ammo Power is currently activated.

<sub>Further testing needed: Whether a Squad Ammo upgrade at Rank 4 combined with increased capacity from Rank 5 increases ammo capacity for the whole squad.</sub>
<sub>Edit:**Yes.**</sub>

Comment: That is a sadness.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, it appears that ammo bonuses from squad members do not work at all. For instance, if Shepard has Disruptor ammo with the 30% ammo bonus, Garrus with AP ammo and the 30% ammo bonus, and Vega with Incendiary ammo with the 30% ammo bonus, then Shepard will not have 90% extra ammo because only his 30% bonus is applied to him. This includes if you got the squad-ammo-at-50% trait, as that bonus only applies to the last ammo power activated in the fireteam. The AI does not appear to use ammo, so you might as well have your friends take the headshot damage bonus, because at least that might function.